# What does a dean do?

Tags: university

This is a follow-up question to [What does a head of department do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101061/what-does-a-head-of-department-do)

The University of Waterloo has [a document](https://uwaterloo.ca/secretariat/policies-procedures-guidelines/policy-45) that describes the answer to this question; however the document is rather vague, and it seems to imply that if all the individual heads of departments have their departments in order (which they presumably will most of the time), the dean barely has to do anything. That's at odds with how most deans don't seem to teach/conduct research anymore however. It also seems awkward to be dean unless one is also head of department: the two people would be subordinate to each other depending on situation.

Comment: The job specification for a Dean is what that particular institution decides it is... No one single document will give you a definitive answer...

Comment: The term "dean" is used for many different kinds of academic administrators.  A Dean is often the head of an academic unit that is composed of several academic departments, with department chairs reporting to the dean and the dean reporting to a provost.  However, it's not uncommon to have other deans such as a "Graduate Dean" who administers graduate programs, a "Dean of Students" who handles disicipline matters, and so on.

Comment: Our dean spends his/her day being a busybody :)

Comment: They're middle management, so they do what middle management always does.